# How to prove a function from $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ is bijective.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble with this problem:
$f\colon \mathbb N\times \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ is defined by

$f(i,j)=\dfrac{(i+j-1)(i+j-2)}{2}+i$.

How do you prove that $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$?

Work: I tried to set $f(i,j)=f(a,b)$. Assuming that $f(i,j)\neq f(a,b)$, then I assume $f(i,j)< f(a,b)$and that $i+j=m$ and $a+b=m+r$ for some remainder $r$. I replaced these into my equation and try to obtain a contradiction thus proving that $i=a, j=b$. However, I get stuck after this part and I do not know of a better way of doing this.

Please help.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @Git Gud: "All signs points to yes".

Answer (score 1):

Instead, let $a=i+m$ and $b=j+n$. Then $(i+j-1)(i+j-2)+2i=(i+j+m+n-1)(i+j+m+n-2)+2i+2m$. Try multiply this out and collecting terms. You want that $m,n=0$.

You might ask why is this a more natural substitution. When you make a substitution, you usually don't want to substitute for only some instances of a variable. Notice that in your set up you still have an $a$ term on the end, despite substituting for some of the $a$s, and likewise for $i$

Comment: Thanks, but what is $r$? Is that a remainder?

Comment: Sorry, that should be an m

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes much more sense.

Comment: Hi, so I tried collecting the terms but I cannot get m,n=0.

Answer (score -1):

$$T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$f(i,j)-T(i+j-2)=i > 0$$
$$T(i+j-1)-f(i,j)=j-1≥0$$
$$T(i+j-2)<f(i,j)≤T(i+j-1)$$
Suppose $f(i,j)=f(a,b)$. Now, $T(i+j-2)<f(i,j)≤T(i+j-1)$ and $T(a+b-2)<f(i,j)≤T(a+b-1)$. Again, $T(n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence, hence $a+b=i+j$. But then the relation $f(i,j)=f(a,b)$ gives $i=a$ and $j=b$, hence f is one to one. I leave the work of proving that $f$ is onto upto you.

Comment: It's not at all clear what this answer is supposed to mean; perhaps you meant to edit your previous answer in this thread?

Comment: have you got the complete answer...pls first tell me that..whats the last line???

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. "Last line" of what?

Comment: last line of my answer

Comment: This answer seems to be a follow-up to your previous answer which said "hint: try to use the triangular numbers." In that case, please edit your previous answer to expand it, rather than adding a new one (and please [format your answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) with MathJax; it's quite unreadable in its current state).

Comment: ok...first take the triangular number sequence.
T(n)=n(n+1)/2.then note that f(i,j)-T(i+j-2)=i>o and T(i+j-1)-f(i,j)≤0.Hence T(i+j-2)<f(i,j)≤T(i+j-1).Now can you prove f(i,j) is one-one?? (use the fact T(n) is strictly increasing)

Comment: now can you read it